# Sitecore 6: Duplicate controls appearing on device layout

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Background:
We have a sitecore 6 installation with a bit of custom code to detect devices (and origins), and switch to a different (custom) device definition in sitecore. This has the effect of changing templates, and controls where appropriate. 
This all works fine.
However.

When we select a node in the content tree, go to the Presentation Tab, click Details to get the Layout Details windows, then edit a device item to add controls we see that duplicates are being added to the devices - not just the one we are editing either. It seems to "double up" what is there - but it never changes the "Default" layout.
I have checked the usual suspects (i.e. all connection strings are correct, pointing to the right databases) but I still get duplicates on saving. The duplicate does not appear on edit - but save - it seems.
Any suggestions on how to track this down, as its causing a nightmare for us.
[image]
Sitecore Version : 6.4.1 (rev:110324)
Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue that can be solved by specifying a layout (Mobile Layout and Main Layout, in your case) on the standard values of your template.

Comment: Hi Derek, just noticed that on the change log for 6.5. Is it worth updating to 6.5, or will that just create more hassles?

Comment: If it helps any, I just got an email this morning saying that 6.5 is now the recommended version.

Comment: Makes the decision easy - thanks guys, the upgrade will be planned :)